# Can you help me identify my bike please?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

Bought this bike off a friend, but it has been repainted and I am just curious as to what kind of bike it is.

Seat, and both tires are not stock. I have replaced all of those since I bought it.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I have been researching the serial number hoping that I may find something. But haven’t. In case that makes any difference the SN is rcy10010578

Comment: After repaint it would be very difficult to identify the frame, it's somewhat generic and has entry level components. Are there any stamped words around the frame? Maybe in BB or dropout areas? Is there any branding left on the fork?

Comment: Looks more like someone peeled off the decals rather than a repaint.  Notice the black around the BB with a white/lighter join strip?    That's original paint.

Comment: have you tried asking your friend what it was ?  And why it was done like that ?      The serial number is useless for identification unless you know the maker already,

Comment: No, no stamped words and my friend bought it like this. Unfortunately. It’s not a huge deal, was just looking at it and was curious as to what it was.

Answer (score -2):

Firestone mb3 mountain bike aluminum

Comment: I tried looking that up on google and couldn’t find any results for a “Firestone mb3”.

Comment: There is a "Bridgestone MB-3" but every photo of them shows a 90's rigid with straight steel tubes.  OPs bike is clearly a more recent frame construction.

Comment: @erik please use the "edit" link to add more information to expand the answer and why you think its that bike.